# Ionic 3 and angular google maps - Map is not loading in real device

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular-google-maps

I am trying to create a app with Ionic 3, and I used Angular Google maps(Agm). Its working fine in browser and some mobile devices. But in some mobile devices google map is not loading.

> In app.module.ts

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';

imports: [
BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
    tabsHideOnSubPages:true
  }),
  AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'XXX',libraries: ["places"],region: 'IN'})
]
```

[image: Screen shot of page]

Comment: are you waiting for platform ready before you load it?  Can you share the code where you are actually loading the map please?  HTML and ts.

Comment: `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
<!-- Other imports -->

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    RelativeTime,
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({apiKey: 'xxx',libraries: ["places"]})
  ],
  exports : [RelativeTime],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}`